# How to use savepoints SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I created a `SQLQuery.sql` in SQL Server with this content:

```
declare @sql int;

select @sql = count(1) from sys.tables

save tran one
print @sql

select @sql = 0
save tran two

print @sql
rollback tran one

print @sql
```

I would expect result as:

```
n
0
n
```

What is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transactions don't affect local variables, they're there to allow you to batch up sets of statements that will change the contents of the database.  I've tweaked your example to illustrate that:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
declare @sql int;
select @sql = count(1) from sys.tables
print @sql
save transaction one
CREATE TABLE TEMP (a varchar(1))
select @sql = count(1) from sys.tables
print @sql
select @sql = count(1) from sys.tables
save tran two
CREATE TABLE TEMP2 (a varchar(1))
select @sql = count(1) from sys.tables
print @sql
rollback tran one
select @sql = count(1) from sys.tables
print @sql
```

Now you can see that the number of tables builds up during the steps of the transaction but the new ones disappear after the ROLLBACK:

```
6
7
8
6
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, I created #tableTemp and inserted there the '@sql' and then i rollbacked the tran and the result was as expected (first i got the '@sql' variable returned then i got null or empty string returned)